# Error when trying to connect WebAPI ASP.NET Core and WCF service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, iis, asp.net-core

I have a WebAPI done with ASP.NET Core that must communicate with an external WCF service that is published in IIS 6.1, but when I try to add a connection to a WCF service with Visual Studio 2015 wizard me the error message:

[image: Step Wizard]

[image: This is the error message]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add this MIME-TYPE to the IIS configuration? Quick way of verifying would be to use Postman to simulate your request to the backend.